# How to disable save dialog box using window form web browser?

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

I can't find any answer to this that fits my requirements. I don't know how to do it. I don't have any code yet since I don't know if this is possible.

I have a user access on the website then there is a button that once I click the file it will download, and the save dialog box will display asking for a folder location. The file doesn't have a link or an address. I think its created in the backend once the Excel button is click.

Now my question is, how can I download the Excel file after I click the button excel without displaying the save dialog box using windows form web browser? Or if that’s not possible. How can I click the save button automatically on the save dialog box then automate the folder location.

Comment: Searching for `c# webbrowser default download path` gave me plenty of results to work with. Good luck.

Comment: Hi Equalsk, I wont post a question here if those result works for me. Thank you for your comment.